Firebase Functions - Missing events logging after third request
Currently we have a Firebase function responsible to listen for ‘xyz_event’.
When this event is sent from both Android/IOS, after the third submission we are still able to see the events (4th, 5th…) , coming on the analytics debug view. However, the event is not triggering the firebase function.
Once the function is triggered it should create a log with the payload
It just starts to trigger the function and create the logs again after 5 minutes.
Just thinking if there is a batch loading on Firebase SDK when submit the events or some setting on firebase to aggregate those events to prevent duplication.
event-functions.ts
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { Constants } from './assets/constants';
import { eventProcessor } from './event-processor';

export const screenView = functions
  .runWith({
    secrets: [
      Constants.FUNCTIONS_SETTINGS.SECRETS.SERVICE.CLIENTKEY,
      Constants.FUNCTIONS_SETTINGS.SECRETS.SERVICE.CLIENTSECRET,
    ],
  })
  .region(Constants.FUNCTIONS_SETTINGS.REGION.EUROPE)
  .analytics.event('footer_click')
  .onLog(async (event) => {
    await eventProcessor.submitEvent(Constants.TYPE.VIEW, event);
    return null;
  });

event-processor.ts
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { AnalyticsEvent } from 'firebase-functions/v1/analytics';
import { buildEventRequestHandler } from './handlers/build-event-request-handler';
import { logging } from './initApp';

const log = logging.log('EventProcessor');

const METADATA = {
  resource: {
    type: 'cloud_function',
    labels: {
      function_name: 'submitEvent',
    }
  }
};

class EventProcessor {
  public async submitEvent(eventType: string, eventPayload: AnalyticsEvent) {
    const firebaseId = eventPayload?.user?.appInfo?.appInstanceId;
    const user = eventPayload?.user;

    const logData = {
      eventType,
      eventPayload
    };

    log.info(log.entry(METADATA, logData));

This line should create the log and after the third request it's not being logged.
log.info(log.entry(METADATA, logData));


First Response from Google Support:
Google Support suggested enabling a retry policy for the Analytics trigger, as triggers are not real-time and cannot guarantee at least one execution. They provided a link to the documentation. link

Follow-Up by Me: I tried enabling the retry policy but found that the function is not failing because it hasn't been triggered. I provided timestamps of the events and screenshots showing that the function ran only three times, missing the last event.

Second Response from Google Support: Google Support explained that the issue is due to Google Analytics' conversion limits. Once the quota is reached, events are treated as regular events instead of conversions, which is why Firebase couldn't trigger the function.

Further Inquiry by Me: I asked how to track the remaining quotas and whether the low number of events is tied to the issue. I also inquired about increasing the quota.

Final Response from Google Support: Google Support acknowledged that the new questions are more related to Google Analytics and passed them on to the Analytics support team.
